# Python collect log data at between specified time range

Tags: python, regex, performance, logging, time

I have a log file of 50 MB where data gets appended at regular time intervals.
when i trigger an event in another application at every 5 minutes, i need to get the current time after event is triggered and need to search log file for a particular word "XXXX" within specified time range (current time - 1 minute to current time + 1 minute)

My log file is of format:

```
[Fri Jun 17 15:26:57.451 2016] -FetchInfo XXXX
[Fri Jun 17 15:26:57.951 2016] -info result
```

Here's my code:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
fp=open(r"D:\other\teraterm.log",'r')
data=fp.read()
fp.close()

c_time=datetime.now()
b_time=c_time-timedelta(seconds=60)
a_time=c_time+timedelta(seconds=60)

b_time=b_time.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]+" "+str(datetime.now().year)
a_time=a_time.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]+" "+str(datetime.now().year)
```

I have got current time and calculated 1 minute before and after and converted as same format in log file.
What is the efficient way to extract data at specific time range and search?
I am using **WINDOWS and PYTHON 2.7**.
Is it appropriate to use regex? if so how to vary just minutes alone that too specific to the time which i provide ? Else, to use any other approach?

**NOTE: i need to load my file after every 5 minutes to search appended new data in file**

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to use a regex for range checks, especially at the borders of days/years/months this can quickly get ugly.

Comment: ya so what other approach can be used ?